# Xcode - Adding an image to a test?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm currently writing tests for a Swift application. During which I need to test processing an image. I'd like to add an example image for testing. From my understanding, which appears to be wrong, I should just be able to drag the image directly into the ProductNameTests directory of Xcode. This adds the image to the target of the tests. Then I try to get the path of the image as such:

```
let imagePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("example_image", ofType: "jpg")
```

This, unfortunately, always returns `nil`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the image to the tests target? If you select the image and look at the inspector panel you should have a tick next to the `<ProjectName>-tests` target.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is, that you search for the image in the main bundle. So at the moment you access the `mainBundle` where your image doesn't exists, because it's in the test-bundle.

So you need to access another bundle. The bundle where your testclass is nested.

For that, use `bundleForClass` instead of `mainBundle`:

```
//The Bundle for your current class
var bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
var path = bundle.pathForResource("example_image", ofType: "jpg")
```

As you see, you load the `NSBundle` for your class and you should now be able to access the image. You could also add the image to your main target and use the `mainBundle` again.

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 3, I'm using this method to load an image in test:

```
func loadImage(named name: String, type:String = "png") throws -> UIImage {
    let bundle = Bundle(for:type(of:self))
    guard let path = bundle.path(forResource: name, ofType: type) else {
        throw NSError(domain: "loadImage", code: 1, userInfo: nil)
    }
    guard let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path) else {
        throw NSError(domain: "loadImage", code: 2, userInfo: nil)
    }
    return image
}
```

And then I use in test:

```
let image = try loadImage(named:"test_image", type: "jpg")
```

Answer (score 3):

in Swift 4 you can do it like so

```
let testImage = UIImage(named: <#Image Name String#>, in: Bundle(for:<#Class Name#>.self), compatibleWith: nil)
```

which is getting an image out of my xcassests for me that is part of my test target and main target

I use this in my `setUp()` function to pass to an image processing class i need to test

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to work with **Images.xcassets**. In that particular case you need to create group (folder) in Xcode, and add an image into the folder (be sure image is copied to Copy Bundle Resources by clicking "Copy items if needed"). And then:

**Swift 5.x:**

```
let path = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).path(forResource: "TestingImage", ofType: "jpg")
```

And make sure the image is checked into the testing target.